# Разбить файл на массив хешей. Ruby

Tags: ruby

Есть файл из текстом:`[#<Task name: "John", date: "2015-07-23">, #<Task name: "Devid", date: "2014-07-21">, #<Task name: "John", date: "2013-01-23">]`

Нужно разбить файл на массив хешей. В конечном итоге нужно, чтобы была возможность удалить какой либо хеш, например удалить все хеши, у которых name: "John".

Comment: Но это же не хэши. Вы сами генерируете такой файл?

Comment: Вы неправильно этот файл формируете -- нужно использовать YAML или Marshal, а не `file.puts task.inspect`

Answer (score 1):

Мне если честно в голову приходит только распарсить содержимое файла и воссоздать массив хэшей

```
str = IO.read('file.txt')

arr = []
str.scan /#<Task([^>]+)>/ do |match|
   name, date = match[0].strip.split(',');
   name_key, name_value = name.split(':')
   date_key, date_value = date.split(':')
   h = {}
   h[name_key] = name_value.gsub(/[\"]+/, '').strip
   h[date_key.strip] = date_value.gsub(/[\"]+/, '').strip
   arr << h
 end

 p arr
```